# Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync result "Not Authenticated" (OAuth2; both Facebook and Google)

Tags: xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-authentication

we are trying to solve the right setup/config to login using facebook and google from one App we created with Xamarin.

We are doing the authentication from the REST Service side using the NET Core 6 framework, and we applied the right configuration on facebook developer site using the developer URL and app_ads.txt file which is located within the root site of the website of our domain and we applied all the configurations required for google as well.

The facebook developer and google api console sites saved the configuration but, when we try to launch the app and it loads the login canvas, it fails in Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync line code with both google and facebook options.

[image]

The code involved is the following:

```
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        const string callbackScheme = "signin-google";

        [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
        public async Task Get([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (!auth.Succeeded
                || auth?.Principal == null
                || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
            {
                // Not authenticated, challenge
                await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
            }
            else
            {
                var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
                var email = string.Empty;
                email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

                // Get parameters to send back to the callback
                var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                    { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                    { "expires", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                    { "email", email }
                };

                // Build the result url
                var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join(
                    "&",
                    qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                    .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

                // Redirect to final url
                Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you guys have any idea what can we do to solve this situation?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

We need some clues or advices for solving this situation.

Comment: Sorry @ToolmakerSteve, title modified because we don't really need consultancy, only help with the logging issue. Thank you.

Comment: First, this is a problem which belongs to asp .net you can add a tag on the problem. Second, I recommend you use the fiddler to test the URL. Third, please do not try to access from a custom middleware before the call to the controller.